# Getting "does not name a type error", but I am naming a type

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm sure I'm overlooking something basic here, but I can't figure it out. I have this bit of code:

```
boost::asio::io_service smpp_io_service;
tcp::endpoint endpoint(ip::address_v4::from_string("192.168.0.25"), 2775);
std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> smpp_socket(new tcp::socket(smpp_io_service));
smpp_socket->connect(endpoint);
SmppClient client(smpp_socket);


void wx_test2Frame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    Logger::out( "Connecting..." );

    try {

        client.setVerbose(true);
        client.bindTransceiver(txtSystemId->GetValue().ToStdString(), txtPassword->GetValue().ToStdString());
        Logger::out( "Connected" );
```

Those top 5 lines work fine when they're inside the `OnButton1Click` function, but as soon as I move them outside (because I don't want the connection to close when the function ends), I get

```
error: smpp_socket does not name a type
```

pointing to the `smpp_socket->connect(endpoint);` line.

But the line directly above names the type as `std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>`, doesn't it?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace scope can contain only declarations, and `smpp_socket->connect(endpoint);` is not a declaration - it's a statement.

C++ standard section [basic.link]/1 reads:

> A program consists of one or more *translation units* (Clause 2) linked together. A translation unit consists of a sequence of declarations.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I've been working with c++ for several weeks now, you'd think I'd have come across this before!

Answer (score 2):

The line with the error is in global scope and it is not a declaration or class/method/function definition - is it a function call. You have to do that inside a function.